# POST to slim with ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I'm trying to POST data using jQuery's ajax to my slim api.

here is the jQuery

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'/api/insert',dataType:'json',data:{name:'matname',label:'Material Name'},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
});​
```

and the slim index.php

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
function json($obj) {
    header('Content-Type','application/json');
    return json_encode($obj);
}

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/insert', function () {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $inputs = json_decode($request->getBody());
    echo json($inputs);
});
?>
```

There is also a $app->get() in the index.php and if I remove that I get a 405 Method Not Allowed when trying to POST. It's apparent I'm not performing a POST and It's actually invoking a GET. I need to know what to do in order to POST via jquery. This is all happening on the same domain localhost

Here is the network activity for the post:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/api/insert
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:96
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=bhj4oot5epdi2rqkn45m0oqgr0
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
{"fid":3,"table":"input","label":"Material Name","name":"matname","type":"text","mandatory":"Y"}
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 12 Dec 2012 15:49:15 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.15
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to see what the actual request looks like, watch the Net tab in Firebug or Chrome dev tools, you can see if the request fires, and its type.

Comment: I've add the network activity for the post

Comment: Turns out the issue was with my .htaccess file on the /api directory. It's working as expected now

Comment: Ah, that would explain it then because I was just going to say that the request looks fine.

Comment: It might be helpful to say what was exactly wrong with your .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Request is going to `/api/insert`

Your slim matches `/insert`

Should be same.

Another thing is you have DAV module installed on apache
that allows you to switch on and off accepted methods

check your apache config (site config) that POST methods are allowed.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html

Comment: That's not the problem, the slim app is in the /api directory, my other get() functions are working without /api in the resource URI if I change the resource URI in the post() function to /api/insert it causes a 404

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$inputs = json_decode($request->getBody(),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

include a trailing slash in the Slim post definition

```
$app->post('/insert/', function () {
```